# LibGit2Sharp has archived diff files

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

In our company we have several dynamic structures consisting of text files.

We have several automated processes that use libgit2sharp to store these structures in Git repos.

However, lately these automated repos have started showing production files containing artifacts such as this:

```
# eng 0
<<<<<<< HEAD
# value 27.6000
=======
# value 25.2000
>>>>>>> master
)
```

I recognize the format in that it is git's native way of visualizing differences when using "git diff" command. Furthermore, the difference illustrated in these files are very likely the actual differences encountered when comparing two versions of the production structures.

However, of course I do not want files to be checkied in like that. I didn't even know that libgit2sharp could produce this format. When does it do that and where is that (presumably temporary) file located? I would suspect that some algorithm inadvertently has checked in an artifact from inside the .git folder, but that does not make any sense either since the file is at the correct location in the working tree (correct subfolder three levels deep).

I have been looking over the various code bases for automated checkin, but I suspect that there is something specific to look for. Can anybody help me out? Is there any critical stage of diff'ing where the original source file is altered like this where I should not be invoking the Repo.Stage() method?

Comment: Do you check for conflicts during your automated staging/committing process?

Comment: That's a good question. I am testing right now. I can see that the file indeed looks like this when I am in a merge conflict. Furthermore, when the repo is in that state and "git status" is showing "both modified", LibGit2Sharp is merely showing Removed|Untracked for the same file and repo. So there may be something similar going on. Do you know if this merge-conflict-induced file change can happen even if there is no merge (we do not merge in the automated process, only attempt to roll forward).

Comment: Regarding *"Furthermore, when the repo is in that state and "git status" is showing "both modified", LibGit2Sharp is merely showing Removed|Untracked for the same file and repo.", could you please open a issue in the **[tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)** with a slight repro case?

Comment: In order to properly attempt at answering, I may need some more info about your process. Especially the "only attempt to roll forward" part. Are you dealing with different branches? Could those branches independently modify the same files?

Comment: The case is easily reproduceable. I will add an issue. The automated process is not working in branches, but I have found that parts of it will operate in detached HEAD state, which effectively may work as if we were in different branches. But there is no automated merging, so I do not see when this mergeable hybrid-file would be produced (or checked in).

Comment: Related issue : https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/881